# C++ Why doesn't my constructor work?

Tags: class, constructor

I'm using visual c++ 2010 and I'm having trouble with class constructors. I've written it exactly as my instructor described and I can't seem to figure out why it wont compile.

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

class Account
{
public:
Insert other functions here...
Account(float b)
{
    Balance = b;
}

private:
float &Balance;
}

Int main()
{   
float withdraw,deposit;
Account myAccount(100.00);

cout << "Enter the amount you would like to withdraw:" << endl;
cin >> withdraw;
MyAccount.debt(withdraw);
cout << "Your balance is now "<< endl;
MyAccount.showAccountInfo();
cout << endl;
cout << "Enter the amount you would like to deposit: " << endl;
cin >> deposit;
myAccount.credit(deposit);
cout << "Your balance now is " << endl;
MyAccount.showAccountInfo();
cout << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you have declared the member Balance as a reference and you are calling the constructor with a constant (i.e. 100.00), you must pass a variable name to the contructor or declare the member without the reference operator.

Comment: I sincerely thought I'd need that to make the balance stay the same but you saved me right there.
Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the balance in different parts of the process you could try it with dynamic memory.

For instance:

```
class Account
{
 public:
 Insert other functions here...
 Account(float* b)
 {
  Balance = b;
 }

 private:
 float* Balance;
}

Int main()
{   
 float withdraw,deposit;
 Account myAccount(new float(100.0));

 cout << "Enter the amount you would like to withdraw:" << endl;
 cin >> withdraw;
 MyAccount.debt(withdraw);
 cout << "Your balance is now "<< endl;
 MyAccount.showAccountInfo();
 cout << endl;
 cout << "Enter the amount you would like to deposit: " << endl;
 cin >> deposit;
 myAccount.credit(deposit);
 cout << "Your balance now is " << endl;
 MyAccount.showAccountInfo();
 cout << endl;

 return 0;
```

In the updating balance method, you should unreference the pointer:

For instance...

```
 void debt(float withdraw){
     *balance -= withdraw;
 }
```

Thanks, Regards.